# I can not reproduce html5-video on a site

Tags: html, html5-video

On my local server, the html5-video is reproduced in all browsers, but on the web server it refuses to be reproduced.

Here's the code:

```
<video controls width="640" height="360" autoplay="true">
<source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HTTP monitor, such as the one built into Firebug (on the ‘Net’ tab) to see what the response to the HTTP request for the video file is.

Possibly the production web server is returning the wrong `Content-Type` for `.ogv` and/or `.mp4` files. (It should be `video/ogg` and `video/mp4`, respectively.) If so, you would need to configure it to add the new MIME media types; how you do this depends on what server software you are using.

Comment: Agreed, it's very likely the server isn't returning the right MIME-type.  See: http://debugfix.com/2011/11/html5-video-works-locally-server/